# Images not showing up with visual composer in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, visual-composer

The 3 images on the home page of [aaleather.com](http://aaleather.com) are no longer showing up, and I can't figure out why.  The content was added with the WPBaker Visual Composer and they were there previously with no problems.  I don't know what would cause them to decide not to show up anymore!

The links they direct to still work.  The title and text below them are there.  Just the images aren't appearing.

I checked to make sure the images are still in our media uploads.

And as I was just looking at the elements in the dev tools, I noticed the img tags are not self closing.  I don't know if that matters here?  If you have any idea what is going on here, I could use some help!  Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBvrx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the images are loading fine from our side, the reason might be with the stored cookies. try the below steps in order.

1. CTRL + F5(refresh) your browser.
   if that doesn't work.
2. Try to deactivate the recent plugins you installed one by one and see which one is causing the issue and find an alternative to that plugin.

Comment: It was a cache plugin that seemed to be causing the issue.  But I don't know why it was never a problem before though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a backup of your website using wp clone or another plugin for emergency
2. download the latest version of visual composer plugin
3. deactivate , then delete the existing visual composer plugin (do not delete the pages by mistake)
4. upload the latest version of visual composer plugin and activate it
5. Try refreshing your webpage if that helps
6. if not, go to "edit that page" , open that image block and re-add the image, now update page and see the progress.

Comment: This worked for me:
-deactivate, then delete the existing visual composer plugin
-upload the latest version of visual composer plugin and activate it
/// No need to back up, if you dont have a plugin on hand already- It takes too much time, rather than fixing the main issue